# What is the simplest way to stack words above and below arrows for chemical formulae?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, mhchem

I want a result like this. Also, is it possible to force all text in certain math environment to be mathrm?

[image]

One solution is to use `mhchem` package with `\ce` command

```
\ce{6CO2 + H2O ->[sunlight][photosynthesis] C6H12O6 + 6O2}
```

The result is beautiful, but I will wait for enhanced answers

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        6 \, \mathrm{CO_{2}} + \mathrm{H_{2}O} &\to \mathrm{C_{6}H_{12}O_{6}} + 6 \, \mathrm{O_{2}}
    \end{alignat*}
    
    \begin{equation*}
        \ce{6CO2 ->[sunlight][photosynthesis] C6H12O6 + 6O2}
    \end{equation*}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Remark: I wrote and posted this answer before I noticed that the OP had rewritten the query to provide a solution based on the `\ce` macro.)

You should really familiarize yourself with one or more of the chemistry packages written for LaTeX. For instance, with the [mhchem](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) package and its `\ce` user macro, you could write the chemical reaction as

```
\ce{6CO2 + H2O ->[sunlight][photosynthesis] C6H12O6 + 6O2}
```

`\ce` produces the same output in both text and math mode.

Aside: I think it should say `6H2O`, not just `H2O`, on the left hand side. That, or you're missing parentheses around `CO2 + H2O`.

Another well-known LaTeX package used for chemistry writing is [chemformula](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemformula).

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{6CO2 + H2O ->[sunlight][photosynthesis] C6H12O6 + 6O2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not need to write chemical formulae. Is it possible to align multiple arrows below each other? :)

Comment: Yes, you are right about this.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - Please study the section "Aligning equations" at the bottom of page 12 of the user guide of the `mhchem` package. (To open the user guide in a pdf browser, type `texdoc mhchem` in a command window.)